# Загрузка файла через $.ajax на java сервер

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, файлы

Есть такой код ajax вызова -

```
this.ajaxGetJsonAndReady = function(type, url, data, onSuccess, processData, contentType) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/" + url,
        type: type,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        processData: processData,
        contentType: contentType,
        success: function(json) {
            if (json.error) {
                error(json.error);
            } else {
                onSuccess(json.data);
                ready();
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            error();
        }
    });
}
```

В него передаю data отсюда -

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer($(this)[0].files[0]);

var array = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
//var binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);

var data = {};
data.test = array;

utils.ajaxGetJsonAndReady("GET", "fileUpload", data, function (processData) {
}, true, 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Серверная часть:
web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>web.framework.core.Servlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>configurationClass</param-name>
        <param-value>web.config.ServletConfigurationImpl</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/ui2/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet (сюда приходит все не так, как ожидается):

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

protected ServletConfiguration configuration;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    try {
        //noinspection unchecked
        val configClass = (Class<ServletConfiguration>) Class.forName(config.getInitParameter("configurationClass"));
        this.configuration = configClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ServletException(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest hrq, HttpServletResponse hre) {
    RequestMethod method;
    RequestHandler handler;
    try {
        method = RequestMethod.valueOf(hrq.getMethod());
        String uri = getRequestUri(hrq);
        val pathParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
        val params = hrq.getParameterMap();  // Вот здесь должны быть корректные параметры.
        handler = configuration.uriToHandlerMapper.createHandler(method, uri, pathParams, params);
        if (handler == null) {
            sendError(hrq, hre, HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
        }
        if (!handler.acceptMethods.contains(method)) {
            throw new Exception("Request method is not acceptable");
        }

        //noinspection unchecked
        handler.params = configuration.requestParamsParser.parse(pathParams, hrq.getParameterMap(), handler);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error("Request dispatcher or parameter parser failed, responding error 400", e);
        sendError(hrq, hre, HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
        return;
    }

    try {
        handler.requestMethod = method;
        handler.httpServletRequest = hrq;
        handler.httpServletResponse = hre;
        handler.execute();
        hre.flushBuffer();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error("Request handler failed, responding error 500", e);
        sendError(hrq, hre, HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
protected String getRequestUri(HttpServletRequest hrq) {
    String uri = hrq.getServletPath();
    String pathInfo = hrq.getPathInfo();
    if (pathInfo != null) {
        uri += pathInfo;
    }
    return uri;
}

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
protected void sendError(HttpServletRequest hrq, HttpServletResponse hre, int status) {
    try {
        val handler = configuration.uriToHandlerMapper.createErrorHandler(hrq, status);
        handler.httpServletRequest = hrq;
        handler.httpServletResponse = hre;
        handler.execute();
        hre.flushBuffer();
    } catch (Throwable e2) {
        // createErrorHandler() failed, I/O error, or response is already committed. Nothing we can do.
    }
}
```

Но на сервер приходит массив параметров, а не один параметр с именем test. 
Что я делаю не так? Поправки и уточнения приветствуются!

Так же ищу другие работающие способы передать файл на сервер.

Comment: Что этот код делает и где серверная часть?

Comment: @RomanC, этот код берет загруженный файл и передает на java сервер.По идее, добавил серверную часть.

Comment: для файлов POST же надо, у GET запроса другая семантика, например он может быть закеширован сетевым устройством

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, но такой вариант пока единственный, при котором что нибудь приходит на сервер. При Post и FormData() приходит пустота, к примеру.